# How do I autofilter using an array for criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am just learning about using arrays and am a bit stuck on how to use arrays as an input for criteria in autofiltering. I would like to set an array with values and then filter an excel spreadsheet using those same values. I did the below code, but it keeps throwing up an error when I try to autofilter

**Here is my code**

```
Dim I As Integer
ReDim arr(1 to var) As Variant 'var is defined in a different function with a #
I = 1
For Each rngValue In rngValues.cells 'rngValues is defined in a different function
    If rngValue ="c" then
       arr(I)=rngValue.Offset(0,2)
    End If
    I = I +1
Next rngValue

arr(I) = "="

With ws1
    .[A1].Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, operator:xlfiltervalues
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this

```
   fil = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("list")))) ' here list is the name of the range
    Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=fil, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'it will only filter the list values
```

Comment: I tried something similar already, but I am using an Array not a range.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Range value to array faster by directly passing it like below:

```
Dim arr As Variant '~~> no need to re-dimension
arr = Application.Transpose(rngValues) '~~> Transpose produces 1D array
ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, arr, xlFilterValues
```

Note that *rngValue* should contain one dimension Range area only.
If however you want to stick with your logic; also to handle 2-dimension Range or non contiguous ranges, below should work:

```
Dim i As Long: i = 1
ReDim arr(1 to rngValues.Cells.Count)
For Each rngValue In rngValues
    arr(i) = rngValue.Value
    i = i + 1
Next
ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, arr, xlFilterValues
```

In any of the scenarios, make sure that the array produced to be used as filter is 1D.

Comment: Thanks ! Just curious- how is the second code different from what I tried? The issue I'm having is that I also only want some of the values from the myvalues range not all of them that's why I went with an array

Comment: I tried the second code and it still resulted in auto filter method of range class failed error

Comment: @Monduras The only difference is you use evaluated Range `[A1]`. The logic is basically the same. I see no reason why it shouldn't work. In your edited code, I think you should iterate I inside your if statement.