# Use a variable Excel range to use in autofilter VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched a lot and tried a lot of different things, but I can't get the following to work.

I have a range of IDs that I generate. I then want to filter a range of data to produce a filtered output of just the specified IDs. However, whatever I try, my filtered output just returns a blank range.

Please note: my range of IDs varies in size each time I run this process. I've included a very simplistic set of data to illustrate my point - my real data is far more complex than my example.

The code I have at the moment:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Template As Workbook
    Set Template = ThisWorkbook
    Dim IDs, Report As Worksheet
    Set IDs = Template.Worksheets("IDs")
    Set Report = Template.Worksheets("Report")

    Dim LastRowIDs As Long
    LastRowIDs = IDs.Range("A" & IDs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim IDsArray As Variant

    IDsArray = IDs.Range("A2:A" & LastRowIDs)

    Dim LastRowReport As Long
    LastRowReport = Report.Range("A" & Report.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Report.AutoFilterMode = False
    Report.Range("A1:C" & LastRowReport).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(IDsArray), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I would say I'm a moderately basic user of VBA so please explain any answers.

[Range to filter on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5pnO.png)

[Data to be filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT4A8.png)

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3iql.png)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add tags around the code.. Makes it easier to read and understand... or highlight the code and press ctrl + k

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153818/how-do-i-autofilter-using-an-array-for-criteria should answer your question.

Comment: I feel that my code is doing the exact same thing as the solution in your link - can you please explain why mine doesn't work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Excel likes it's autofilter arrays as strings. So you need to convert the array to string values. Then it works.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Template As Workbook
    Set Template = ThisWorkbook
    Dim IDs, Report As Worksheet
    Set IDs = Template.Worksheets("IDs")
    Set Report = Template.Worksheets("Report")

    Dim LastRowIDs As Long
    LastRowIDs = IDs.Range("A" & IDs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim IDsArray As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String, i As Integer
    IDsArray = Application.Transpose(IDs.Range("A2:A" & LastRowIDs))
    For i = LBound(IDsArray) To UBound(IDsArray)
        sTemp = "," & IDsArray(i) & sTemp
    Next i
    IDsArray = Split(Mid(sTemp, 2), ",")

    Dim LastRowReport As Long
    LastRowReport = Report.Range("A" & Report.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Report.AutoFilterMode = False
    Report.Range("A1:C" & LastRowReport).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=IDsArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```